# json/xml schema for all RESTFUL API in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

> DOCUSIGN- like SOAP based API call three is WSDL. 
>   So is there any json/xml schema for all   RESTFUL APIs in docusign.

Answer (score 2):

This page contains JSON/XML request/response format for all DocuSign REST API Operations:  https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the REST API References section here:
https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm

Though I've never seen the one Kim Brandl cited, that one is much prettier.